# HTML/Javascript Offline Tracking Localhost Without Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, localhost, local-storage

What I am looking to accomplish is when a website is hosted locally on the localhost if it would be possible to track the clicks/navigation kind of like google analytics does but a very simplified version of having time stamps, and counts using primarily HTML5 and Javascript. I haven't found much information doing something like this with localstorage either. Primary reason is to keep tracking information for what information would be accessed without being online/needing a internet connection.

If I remember correctly one of the issues of localhost, is the inability to have scripts change files on the localhost directly(AJAX) and would require to be sent to a server. Preferred if it did not require server side languages such as php, etc.. Since how this would be used would not always have mamap/wamap installed.

Any help would be great, or a direction.

Comment: Where exactly do you wish to store the analytics? who needs to be able to access them? Having analytics on an offline file would only be visible to the person who is using the offline file. Doesn't sound very useful.

Comment: Hey @Kevin. It would be viewed after say the event, so storing it locally would be ideal since there would be no internet connection.

Comment: Then yes, local storage or cookies would be the place to do it. Do you have an actual question or problem you are trying to solve?